# How to Cache a Method with two parameters in Spring-Mvc

Tags: java, rest, spring-mvc, ehcache

I want  to convert transactions's amount fields to another currency and I decided to use cache mechanism with @Cacheable annotations. In this cacheable method, I call an rest api method to get currency rate. According to I am setting caching period to 60 seconds and always send same parameters, program executes cacheable methods scope for each coming transactions.

I want to see logs for every minutes or calling different parameter, I used log.error() because of this.

#### CurrencyConverterService.java

```java
@Service
public class CurrencyConverterService {
    private Logger log = LogManager.getLogger(CurrencyConverterService.class);
    @Autowired
    private ICurrencyService currencyService;

    int counter=0;

    @Cacheable(value = "allCurrency")
    public Float getCurrencyRate(String targetCurrCode, String baseCurrCode){
        log.error("getCurrencyRate called " +targetCurrCode +" - "+baseCurrCode+" - counter "+ counter+" Times");
        counter++;
        Float rate = currencyService.calculateParity(targetCurrCode, baseCurrCode);
        return rate;
    }

    public BigDecimal currencyConverter(Object value, String targetCurrCode, String baseCurrCode){
        float rate;

        if (baseCurrCode.equals(targetCurrCode)){
            rate = 1.0f;
        }else{
            rate = getCurrencyRate(targetCurrCode, baseCurrCode);
        }
        return ((BigDecimal)value).multiply(new BigDecimal(rate));
    }
}
```

#### Demo.java

```java
@Service
public class Demo{
    @Autowired
    public ApplicationContext appContext;
    public CurrencyConverterService currencyConverterService;

    public void getCurrencyFromAPI(Object value, String targetCurrCode, String baseCurrCode){
        ....
        currencyConverterService = (CurrencyConverterService) appContext.getBean("currencyConverterService");
        currencyConverterService.currencyConverter(value, targetCurrCode, baseCurrCode);
        ....

    }
}
```

#### ehcache.xml

```xml
<ehcache
        xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
        xsi:noNamespaceSchemaLocation="http://ehcache.org/ehcache.xsd"
        updateCheck="false" monitoring="off" dynamicConfig="true">

    <diskStore path="java.io.tmpdir"/>

    <cache
            name="allCurrency"
            eternal="false"
            maxElementsInMemory="200"
            maxElementsOnDisk="10000"
            timeToIdleSeconds="600"
            timeToLiveSeconds="600"
            overflowToDisk="true"
            diskExpiryThreadIntervalSeconds="86400"
            memoryStoreEvictionPolicy="LFU"/>
</ehcache>
```

If I send 1000 transactions in four minutes. I see outputs below;

getCurrencyRate calleddd EUR-USD - counter 1 times
getCurrencyRate calleddd EUR-USD - counter 2 times
...
getCurrencyRate calleddd EUR-USD - counter 999 times
getCurrencyRate calleddd EUR-USD - counter 1000 times

but I want to see like below;

getCurrencyRate calleddd EUR-USD - counter 1 times
getCurrencyRate calleddd EUR-USD - counter 2 times
getCurrencyRate calleddd EUR-USD - counter 3 times
getCurrencyRate calleddd EUR-USD - counter 4 times

Thank you for your help.

Comment: I don't think multiple parameters is the issue; all parameters are considered by [default](https://docs.spring.io/spring/docs/current/spring-framework-reference/integration.html#cache-annotations-cacheable-default-key). Pls share more details about the code, such as the main class and how's this method being used

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I fixed this problem. If I call cached method from other methods in same class like above, does not work. If I call directly cached method from other classes, works properly. I should use like below;

#### Demo.java

```java
@Service
public class Demo{
    @Autowired
    public ApplicationContext appContext;
    public CurrencyConverterService currencyConverterService;

    public void getCurrencyFromAPI(Object value, String targetCurrCode, String baseCurrCode){
        ....
        currencyConverterService = (CurrencyConverterService) appContext.getBean("currencyConverterService");
        currencyConverter(value, targetCurrCode, baseCurrCode);
        ....

    }

    public BigDecimal currencyConverter(Object value, String targetCurrCode, String baseCurrCode){
        float rate;

        if (baseCurrCode.equals(targetCurrCode)){
            rate = 1.0f;
        }else{
            rate = currencyConverterService.getCurrencyRate(targetCurrCode, baseCurrCode);
        }
        return ((BigDecimal)value).multiply(new BigDecimal(rate));
    }

}
```

#### CurrencyConverterService.java

```java
@Service
public class CurrencyConverterService {
    private Logger log = LogManager.getLogger(CurrencyConverterService.class);
    @Autowired
    private ICurrencyService currencyService;

    int counter=0;

    @Cacheable(value = "allCurrency")
    public Float getCurrencyRate(String targetCurrCode, String baseCurrCode){
        log.error("getCurrencyRate called " +targetCurrCode +" - "+baseCurrCode+" - counter "+ counter+" Times");
        counter++;
        Float rate = currencyService.calculateParity(targetCurrCode, baseCurrCode);
        return rate;
    }
}
```